# can not find requestLEScan() method webbluetooth

Tags: web-bluetooth

I want to use requestLEScan method to scan ble peripheral devices, but I cannot find requestLEScan method.
I wrote below following [this doc](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/scanning.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<button id="test" onclick="onButtonClick()">test</button>

<script>
function onButtonClick() {
  navigator.bluetooth.requestLEScan({
    filters: [{manufacturerData: {0x004C: {dataPrefix: new Uint8Array([
      0x02, 0x15, // iBeacon identifier.
      0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15  // My beacon UUID.
    ])}}}],
    options: {
      keepRepeatedDevices: true,
    }
  }).then(() => {
    navigator.bluetooth.addEventListener('advertisementreceived', event => {
    let appleData = event.manufacturerData.get(0x004C);
  if (appleData.byteLength != 23) {
    // Isn’t an iBeacon.
    return;
  }
  let major = appleData.getUint16(18, false);
  let minor = appleData.getUint16(20, false);
  let txPowerAt1m = -appleData.getInt8(22);
  let pathLossVs1m = txPowerAt1m - event.rssi;

    });
  })
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it cause error like this.

[image: index_html_ _index_html_-_web_bluetooth_-____play_ground_web_bluetooth_]

Also, I checked object and it only has requestDevice() method

[image: index_html]

Answer (score 3):

According to the [WebBluetooth implementation status page](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#scanning-api), Chrome has not implemented `requestLEScan` so far. Depending on your device, you may be able to use the regular `requestDevice` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, can I get major minor with requestDevice method?
Also I want to do scanning background.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do constant scanning with `requestDevice`; that API is designed so that the user can pair a device once. It may be possible to get the beacon data, but I highly doubt it (you can [simply try it](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html?allDevices=true) though).